# Call aspnet webservice like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Im making some of my ajax visible for google. To do that, I have to provide html snapshots of my content based on a querystring (escaped fragment). The problems is, some of my html are returned by webservices calls.

I have a class, called Site.ajax._search, with webmethods inside, like:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string ReadSearch(string nm_what, string nm_where, int pageindex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine, I would also make it static:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string ReadSearch(string nm_what, string nm_where, int pageindex)
{
}

//from another page
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //example
    string s = Search.ReadSearch("this","here",2); //add namespace and references needed
}
```

[Why do ASP.NET AJAX page methods have to be static?](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)

Comment: Is there any problem concerning make the method static?